# Perl Escape Quotes Problem

Tags: java, perl, command-line

Pardon me if this is too trivial.

I am doing an XSLT by calling system() in Perl script like this:

```
system("java -Xms256m -Xmx512m -jar $saxonJar -o $tmpFile $inFile $xslFile $saxonParams");
```

$inFile is a string that contains a relative path to the xml file that is going to be translated using XSLT.This worked fine except for those $inFile that has space in the string, for example, like "Intro to Dance.htm", then it will report a syntax error.

If this is in MS-DOS, then I can easiliy get around this problem by putting a quote around the $inFile string in the XSLT command. I did try putting escape in the above command like:

```
system("java -Xms256m -Xmx512m -jar $saxonJar -o $tmpFile \"$inFile\" $xslFile $saxonParams");
```

It does not work. Could anybody help how should I put quotes around $inFile?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can avoid the shell (and thus shell-escaping problems) by passing your command line to `system` as a list instead. Try

```
system( 'java', '-Xms256m', '-Xmx512m', '-jar', $saxonJar, '-o', $tmpFile, $inFile, $xslFile, $saxonParams );
```

See the perldoc for [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) for more on how this works.

Comment: @friedo: Tried, but got errors like: String found where operator expected at ./mot_publish.pl line 121, near "'java' '-Xms256m'"
        (Missing operator before  '-Xms256m'?). Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You need a comma between each item in the list.

Comment: @Robert: friedo's code looks correct. Are you certain you've copied it correctly? Either you made a mistake in copying, or the error is one or two lines above the reported line (that's a general problem with parsing errors like that). edit: friedo's already found the problem.

Comment: @friedo: Sorry it is my bad, I forgot to copy the comma, let me try again.

Comment: @friedo: Worked with just a few erros. But I actually think of another way that is much better: can we change the file name of the actual file stored on disk by replacing the white space into underscore. My statement to loop through all files in the directory        @pub=`ls $sourceDir | grep '\.htm' | grep -v Default |  head  -550`;

Comment: @Robert : `find . -name '* *' | (while read file ; do mv "$file" $(echo $file | sed -e 's/ /_/g;') ; done )`

Answer (score 1):

Is this, in fact, MS-DOS?

You said it didn't work, but not what actually happened.  Did you get an error?  What was it?

If this is on a Unixish system, just substitute single quotation marks:

```
system("java -Xms256m -Xmx512m -jar $saxonJar -o $tmpFile '$inFile' $xslFile $saxonParams");
```

I don't know if that will work on MS-DOS or not.

If the filename contains `"` or `'` it becomes a little more complex, because those will need to be preserved at the shell level:

```
$inFile =~ s/(['"])/\\$1/g;
system("java -Xms256m -Xmx512m -jar $saxonJar -o $tmpFile \"$inFile\" $xslFile $saxonParams");
```

(Or something similar.)

Better still, use the multi-argument form:

```
system('java', '-Xms256m', '-Xmx512m', '-jar', $saxonJar, '-o', $tmpFile,
       $inFile, $xslFile, $saxonParams);
```

and let the interpreter and the shell figure it out.

Comment: thanks. Is "$inFile =~ s/(['"])/\\$1/g;" going to surround the $inFile with quotes?

Comment: @Robert : No, it's going to replace all `"` with `\"` and all `'` with `\'`.  In other words, escaping the quotes to make it safer to enclose the whole thing in quotation marks.  The multi-argument solution is better, though, if it'll work.